'ls *(/)' shows nothing if there is only one empty directory
I have a directory ~/test with two empty directories there: emptydir and emptydir2.
ls ~/test/*(/) shows them both:
~/test/emptydir:

~/test/emptydir2:

But if there is only one empty directory there, ls ~/test/*(/) shows nothing. Why is it so?

That command would list the content of the directories. Is that what you want? If not, you likely want to use ls with its -d option.

Thanks, ls -d makes output look better, and it also shows a directory if there is only one. But I still don't understand why ls *(/), given that a user wants content, doesn't show single empty dir, but nevertheless shows two or more empty ones.

I suggest you update your question with an actual example showing what you're seeing.

@Kusalananda Done, sorry.

This is just the default behavior of ls when passed multiple versus a single directory argument I think - see for example ls: Display directory name when only one matches pattern

The ls utility is required to print out the names of the directories whose contents it lists when it is given more than one directory to process on its command line. This is regardless of whether these directories are empty or not.
The following is from the POSIX specification of the ls utility:

If more than one directory, or a combination of non-directory files and directories are written, either as a result of specifying multiple operands, or the -R option, each list of files within a directory shall be preceded by:
"\n%s:\n", <directory name>

The above string may be omitted for the directory named by the operand if only one operand is present. It may also be omitted for dot (.) if no operands are present. If this string is the first thing to be written, the first <newline> shall not be written. This output shall precede the number of units in the directory.

If you want to list the directories themselves, not their content, then use ls with its -d option.

To complement @Kusalananda's answer, note that ls is not the only command that skips printing a header when asked to process only one argument.
In ls dir or ls which is short for ls ., since it's passed only one argument, ls assumes you know what directory you're getting the listing of since you just asked for it. That falls apart here when the directory list is the result of an expansion (here filename generation aka pathname expansion) that happens to result in one and only one entry.
It's the same for grep -- pattern *.txt where grep will not show the file name when *.txt expands to one and only one file, or head -- *.txt (note that passing more than one file to head is not standard though).
The GNU implementation of some of those utilities have options to force printing the header even if passed only one argument like -H / --with-filename for GNU grep or -v / --verbose for GNU head/tail, but  that's not the case of GNU ls.
However, a portable approach that works for many commands is to pass an extra argument to the command in addition to the result of the expansion so as to guarantee at least 2 arguments are passed and post-process the output to remove the corresponding output if needed.
For instance GNU's grep -H -- pattern *.txt could be written portably grep -- pattern /dev/null *.txt (no need to post-process the output as /dev/null is empty so there won't be any match there).
For ls, you can use ls -- /dev/null *(/) | tail -n +3, here using tail -n +3 to remove the listing for /dev/null itself which should come first as POSIX requires that output for non-directory operands be listed first.
